# how to concatenate based on a slash

Tags: excel

Is there a way to concatenate based on a specific character? I've used concatenate in the past based on x number of characters from the left, for example, but I need to concatenate based on a slash.

For example, 
In column a I have part numbers such as 09-K1450V/XXL, 09-K1450V/XXXL, 16-150V/L
16-150V/M, 16-150V/S. What I'm building is a description field that should first contain the size information. So I'd like to pull all information **after** the slash in column a.

Comment: Concatenation is the combining of two or more strings.  You want to Parse or Split based on a character.  Do you want a formula to do such?

Comment: well that would be nice - otherwise, I'd have to go with text to columns to first split away the text after the slash and then take that column and concatenate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you want is:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("/",A1)+1,LEN(A1))
```

[image]

Comment: yea that works! So now I'm trying to remember but can cells handle multiple formulas? In other words, can I to that formula with additional data from other cells?

Comment: Yes you would simple add `& D1` or any other cell.  It will concatenate the result and the value in D1.

Comment: yup I just remember that I needed the & in between each formula.